# Class Loaders Hierarchy

Tags: java, classloader

Why Extensions CL goes after Bootstrap, but before System CL? Aren't classes from "CLASSPATH" and other system modules more important for application then extensions? Or there's another behind all this mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say extension libraries it means extension to the ecosystem provided by default JVM. So any application using the JVM can use the facility of those extension libraries at compile/run time. Application specific libraries as usual are specific to the application only and other appications will not have any knowledge about it. So it becomes more important to give loading preference to a library which may be used by other applications for obvious reasons